# Warning : control port is open but no authentication method has been configured

Tags: configuration, web-proxy

I want to use privoxy and tor to avoid leaks that happen easily on standard web browsers. I've configured privoxy to send web trafic to a port where tor is listening and edited the torrc to listen to this port but I also added `ControlPort auto` which generates a warning when I run `--verify-config` :

> ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible"

I know I should be using some kind of authentification but can't figure out how to do it. Can I just use `--hash-password` ? does this mean I should reconfigure privoxy ?

Config : debian 8, tor 0.2.5.12, privoxy 3.0.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authentication is easy and set in your torrc. See [this tutorial](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html).